# How to design an interface for planning and booking itineraries

Tags: gui-design, design

I'm building a webform application that allows visitors to plan and book an itinerary with multiple pickups and destinations in the same reservation.

A user can add up to 4 'transportations' and will receive an additional discount on each.

Looking at the wireframe below, where should I place the add/remove transportation control?

I would also like the customer to enter their email address (which will unlock an additional discount) and proceed to the next step to complete the reservation by pushing the 'book' button.

I have included a wireframe below. The problem is that I don't know where to place all the buttons and how to make it easy to understand. 
[image: booking]

You can also see how it works on [www.simontaxi.com](http://www.simontaxi.com)

Can you please let me know what you think would be the best practice for this kind of form? I don't think I have ever seen anything similar and I don't know if visitors will understand.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your *question* feels a bit *spam-ish* – or at least as if you're asking for a *review* –– the 'wireframe' resembles quite exacly what already can be found on the (linked) website. Also: check your description meta-tags –– currently google displays "The qTranslate Editor has disabled itself because it hasn't been tested with your WordPress version yet…" where your meta description should be (underneith the link in google SERP).

Comment: the linked website is the actual wireframe because it's my project.. since this is just a project and is not finished yet i don't mind the meta tag of google...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the shopping cart design pattern, which most users are familiar with. You can do something like the following :

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxoM0y.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Hi, i like where you positioned the email and the total price, but i don't see the shopping cart as viable option because it sounds like you are buying something which would be shipped or downloaded.. this is a transportation, it's like booking a ticket of an airplane with a shopping cart.. thanks for your time anyway.. i really apreciate